# How to locate the File-Preferences menu in Lotus Notes in Apple Mac

Tags: mac, lotus-notes

I tried setting up few preferences in Lotus Notes in windows7 using the File->Preferences option in Lotus Notes.

Tried to do the same in Mac as well. Could not locate the File->preferences menu there.

Is there any other location I need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Lotus Notes menu followed by Preferences (or use the standard Mac shortcut for application preferences: CMD+comma).